# How to update the value of an input field with the output of a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete noob in JS since I have been coding in PHP always so here comes the noobs question.
I have a date picker and it works fine but the problem is that when a date has been selected it doesn't update the value of the corresponding input field. the script apparently works using the class name so there will be multiple inputs declared as the date picker using the same class on the same page but I have to update the value of the input fields individually meaning if the user selects `11/28/2020` for input1 only input1 updates with the value, not the other inputs that have been declared as the date picker by the same class.

here is the date picker initialization code I'm using:

```
<script>
    $('.persian-date').persianDatepicker({
        "inline": false,
        "format": "YYYY/MM/DD",
        "viewMode": "day",
        "initialValue": false,
        "minDate": null,
        "maxDate": null,
        "autoClose": true,
        "position": "auto",
        "altFormat": "",
        "altField": "",
        "onlyTimePicker": false,
        "onlySelectOnDate": false,
        "calendarType": "persian",
        "inputDelay": 800,
        "observer": true,
        "calendar": {
            "persian": {
            "locale": "fa",
            "showHint": true,
            "leapYearMode": "algorithmic"
            },
            "gregorian": {
            "locale": "en",
            "showHint": true
            }
        },
        "navigator": {
            "enabled": true,
            "scroll": {
            "enabled": true
            },
            "text": {
            "btnNextText": "<",
            "btnPrevText": ">"
            }
        },
        "toolbox": {
            "enabled": false,
            "calendarSwitch": {
            "enabled": false,
            "format": "MMMM"
            },
            "todayButton": {
            "enabled": false,
            "text": {
                "fa": "امروز",
                "en": "Today"
            }
            },
            "submitButton": {
            "enabled": false,
            "text": {
                "fa": "تایید",
                "en": "Submit"
            }
            },
            "text": {
            "btnToday": "امروز"
            }
        },
        "timePicker": {
            "enabled": false,
            "step": 1,
            "hour": {
            "enabled": false,
            "step": null
            },
            "minute": {
            "enabled": false,
            "step": null
            },
            "second": {
            "enabled": false,
            "step": null
            },
            "meridian": {
            "enabled": false
            }
        },
        "dayPicker": {
            "enabled": true,
            "titleFormat": "YYYY MMMM"
        },
        "monthPicker": {
            "enabled": true,
            "titleFormat": "YYYY"
        },
        "yearPicker": {
            "enabled": true,
            "titleFormat": "YYYY"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add HTML too? It seems like there is Not explicit value, but can’t proof Sinne there is no markup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. here is the markup: `<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-alternative persian-date" placeholder="" id="workExp-end-date" name="workExpEndDate" value="">`

Comment: There should be a submittier-callback , to Devise the value.

Comment: how am i supposed to do that? i don't know anything about JS.